# Combine after $unwind for time series rollup in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, view, nested, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of time-series documents that follow the schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce523fb3e9e92609c54747b"),
    "received" : ISODate("2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "payload" : {
        "tag1" : 0.0,
        "tag2" : 0.0,
        "tag3" : 0.0,
        ...
        "xyz": 0.0
    }
}
```

The received timestamps are ISO8601 and the values inside the payload are doubles. I don't have control over the documents schema.
I receive 1 document per minute, the number of fields inside the payload across time may vary and so can the literals of the keys (the tag names).

I essentially need to do time rollups (hourly, daily, weekly, etc) showing the average of every given tag for the time interval.
After looking at the documentation and related posts (like https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/time-series-data-and-mongodb-part-3--querying-analyzing-and-presenting-timeseries-data), I believe it is possible.
I believe I might need to do something like `unwind` the payload and then apply the aggregation grouping by k,v but this is the furthest I have got:

```
db.my_data.aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "year": {"$year": "$received"}, "month": {"$month": "$received"}, "dayOfMonth": {"$dayOfMonth": "$received"}, "hour": {"$hour": "$received"},
        "p": {"$objectToArray": "$payload"}}
    },
    {"$unwind": "$p"},
    {"$group": {
        _id: {           
            year: "$year",
            month: "$month",
            dayOfMonth: "$dayOfMonth",
            hour: "$hour",
            tag: "$p.k"
        },
        "t_avg": {$avg: "$p.v"},
        }
    },
])
```

However, which this I end up with a bunch of "unwinded" records, as many as tags there are inside the payload:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 6,
        "dayOfMonth" : 1,
        "hour" : 0,
        "tag" : "tag1"
    },
    "t_avg" : 13.1261633627836
},
...
```

That is not what I need. It is critical that the time-rolled records are in exactly the same format as the original ones, this is: `_id`, `received`, and `payload`, so the resulting averages per tag over time have to end up combined in an analogous payload object

```
{ // assuming hour 5th
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "received" : ISODate("2018-06-01T00:05:00.000Z"),
    "payload" : {
        "tag1" : avg for the hour,
        "tag2" : avg for the hour,
        "tag3" : avg for the hour,
        ...
        "xyz": avg for the hour
    }
}
```

I don't know how to achieve this.

The final goal is to create a view with this, so the rolled up averages can be fetched on demand without having to run the query as code from a service. 
I'm not sure if the syntax to create a view differs as compared to the syntax of an aggregated query, I believe it is possible to create a view based on an aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `_id` fields into date (using [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/index.html)) and use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get `payload` built of your dynamically generated values, try:

```
db.my_data.aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "year": {"$year": "$received"}, "month": {"$month": "$received"}, "dayOfMonth": {"$dayOfMonth": "$received"}, "hour": {"$hour": "$received"},
        "p": {"$objectToArray": "$payload"}}
    },
    {"$unwind": "$p"},
    {"$group": {
        _id: {           
            year: "$year",
            month: "$month",
            dayOfMonth: "$dayOfMonth",
            hour: "$hour",
            tag: "$p.k"
        },
        "t_avg": {$avg: "$p.v"},
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $dateFromParts: { year: "$_id.year", month: "$_id.month", day: "$_id.dayOfMonth", hour: "$_id.hour" } },
            payload: { $push: { k: "$_id.tag", v: "$t_avg" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            payload: { $arrayToObject: "$payload" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Awesome!
I eventually came up too with something that works following some double grouping-by post.  

I was looking something like $dateFromParts. Eventually I made it work by truncating the date string ...which I don't like much but I guess it does the trick when aggregating the field. I rather prefer $dateFromParts.

Just a question from ignorance: I understand the 1st group by collects all the tag records, and the 2nd group by recombines the payload from the keys and the aggregation.  
 
Is it any possibility to do the 2 groups by in just one? Something with `$mergeObjects` maybe?

Comment: @diegoruizbarbero they need to be separate since first one is to calculate the averages while second one is to accumulate them into one array - this can't be done  in a one step